# wso2 esb sending dss NumberFormatException with blank input

Tags: wso2, esb, wso2-data-services-server

I have a proxy inside wso2 esb. I used call and I want to send response from call to my outSequence. But it gives me Dss error.I do not use dss at all. Can anyone tell why this error happens and how can I solve this?
this is my proxy code:

```
<proxy xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
   name="FinaltestProxy"
   startOnLoad="true"
   statistics="disable"
   trace="enable"
   transports="https,http,vfs">
<target>
  <inSequence>
        <input type="text"/>
        <output type="xml"/>
     </smooks>
     <iterate attachPath="//csv-set"
              continueParent="true"
              expression="//csv-set/search"
              preservePayload="true"
              sequential="true">
        <target>
           <sequence>
              <call>
                 <endpoint>
                    <address format="soap11"
                             uri="MyEndpoint"/>
                 </endpoint>
              </call>
              <respond/>
           </sequence>
        </target>
     </iterate>
  </inSequence>
  <outSequence>
     <property name="OUT_ONLY" value="true"/>
     <aggregate>
        <completeCondition>
           <messageCount max="100000" min="0"/>
        </completeCondition>
        <onComplete xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope"
                    expression="//Guest">
           <log level="full"/>
           <send>
              <endpoint name="FileEpr">
                 <address format="soap11"
                          uri="MyEndpoint"/>
                 <property name="ContentType" scope="axis2" value="text/xml"/>
              </endpoint>
           </send>
        </onComplete>
     </aggregate>
  </outSequence>
</target>
 /* some code*/
</proxy>
```

and this is my Error:

```
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Nested Exception:-
javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: DS Fault Message: Error in    'SQLQuery.processNormalQuery'
DS Code: DATABASE_ERROR
Source Data Service:-
Name: GuestIdentityService
Location: /ss.dbs
Description: N/A
Default Namespace: http://soa.ut.ac.ir/GuestIdentityService
Current Request Name: searchGuestIdentity
Current Params: {ID=}
Nested Exception:-
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there was a blank line in my input and that cause the problem.

Comment: Hi @Fateme Shahrabi,
How can we handle this blank input? In my case i am having int as datatype for the DB Column called "year", when input is empty it shows the same error, because i set this param type as "Integer" in my DSS Query

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a dataservice called `ss`, and it's being called somehow. Remove it if you don't want it. You can remove it from either UI or file system. It's located in `repository/deployment/server/dataservices/`

Comment: thanks for your reply but when I checked the location I can not see dataservices  and there is no ss.dbs at all

Comment: do you have installed any car files?

Comment: No I didn't install any car file